# Generate samples of size n and apply function in R?

Tags: r, function, optimization, random, statistics

I have the following code to generate my samples of size n, then want to perform an optimise function on the samples. I should get 1000 results from the optimise function but only get 1? Is there a way to perform the optimise function across the rows of 'x'

```
f2d <- function(n){
  x <- replicate(1000, rpois(n, 10))
  optimise(
    f = function(theta){ sum(dpois(x, theta, log = TRUE)) }, 
    interval = c(0,50), 
    maximum = TRUE
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function must be applied to each sample, so define an auxiliary function, `fun`, to be applied to each column. Then, call the function in an `apply` loop.

```
f2d <- function(n){
  fun <- function(y){
    optimise(
      function(theta){ sum(dpois(y, theta, log = TRUE)) }, 
      interval = c(0,50), 
      maximum = TRUE
    )
  }
  # apply the function to each poisson sample
  x <- replicate(1000, rpois(n, 10))
  apply(x, 2, fun)
}

set.seed(2021)
res <- f2d(10)
res <- do.call(rbind, res)

head(res)
#     maximum  objective
#[1,] 9.499999 -26.3231 
#[2,] 11.8     -25.62272
#[3,] 9.799998 -31.49774
#[4,] 10.4     -25.40647
#[5,] 10.4     -31.57375
#[6,] 9.899997 -27.67275
```

Comment: thanks for clearing that up! If I then wanted to take a mean and variance of the 1000 output how is that implemented into the function?

Comment: @Monj Don't complicate the function, for the means there's `colMeans(res)` and for the variance `apply(res, 2, var)`.